# Java: передача параметров по ссылке и значению

Tags: java

В java примитивные типы должны передаваться в функцию по значению, все ссылочные - как ссылки (по сути ссылка передается по значению, но она все еще является ссылкой, поэтому должен достигаться эффект передачи по ссылке). Почему тогда следующий код напечатает 0, если я передаю в функцию не примитивный тип int, а ссылочный Integer?

```
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Integer a = new Integer(0);
        hmm(a);
        System.out.println(a);
    }

    public static void hmm(Integer a)
    {
        a += 5;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Integer` - это же ссылочный тип, а не примитивный `int`? Значит мы передаем копию ссылки, которая указывает на тот же объект, что и в вызывающей функции. Разве не так?

Comment: Ну Вы же меняете значение копии `a`, а не свойства объекта на который эта копия `a` ссылается. Я имею ввиду, что `a += 5` не то же самое, что и например `a.value = 5` (если бы тип a был не Integer)

Comment: Как это понимаю я. Есть объект в куче (он создан в `main` через `new`). На него есть ссылка `a` в функции `main`. В функцию `hmm` передается копия ссылки, которая продолжает ссылаться на тот же самый объект в куче, что и исходная ссылка. Просто ссылок теперь две. Если бы использовался б тип `int`, а не `Integer`, то все бы было правильно, так как тип примитивный. Но тут же ссылочный тип

Answer (score 2):

Операция инкремента у экземпляра `Integer` приводит к созданию нового объекта, а поскольку в метод передаётся копия ссылки, то при инкременте она перестаёт ссылаться на старый объект в куче и начинает ссылаться на новый. Оригинальная ссылка в методе `main` будет ссылаться на старый объект до изменения.

Comment: Можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы изменение значение было видно в вызывающей функции?

Comment: Можно сделать изменяемый класс-обертку над Integer и передавать в метод её

Answer (score 1):

Класс `Integer` является *immutable*, то есть неизменяемым.

По сути код:

```
a+=5;
```

эквивалентен:

```
Integer a = new Integer(a.intValue()+5);
```

То есть создается новый экземпляр `Integer`

Comment: Можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы изменение значение было видно в вызывающей функции?

Comment: Можно, если создать собственный *mutable* класс обертку над `Integer`

Answer (score 1):

Да, действительно, при передаче классов-обёрток вроде Integer, Boolean, Byte и так далее в методы изменения не отражаются на внешних объектах. Всё дело в том, что эти классы являются неизменяемыми. То есть значение, записанное в Integer, изменить нельзя. Когда вы пытаетесь провести операцию, изменяющую значение этой переменной, по факту создаётся новый объект с новым значением.
Подробнее об этом можно прочесть [здесь](https://beauty-of-java.site/java-fundament/peredacha-peremennyh/). Также там описано, почему в Java всё передаётся по значению: и примитивные типы, и объекты. И как не запутаться в этих понятиях

Comment: Слушайте, неужели вы серьёзно думаете, что ваш ответ кому-нибудь принесет пользу? Наверху есть целых два замечательных ответа, которые полностью исчерпывают проблему.

Comment: Моя вера в это непоколебима.

Comment: Ваше дело. Хотя по-моему вы зря тратите время. Отвечали б лучше на новые вопросы.

Comment: @Глеб, похоже главная задача ответов данного автора -- набросать ссылок на некий сайт.